# Does not make sense that I have to have files before import

Tags: github, go, installation, package

How do I import an external package from scratch?

I've written a library package in Go and testing to distribute through github. I am following http://golang.org/doc/code.html and using mac but getting error message

cmd I put is following.

```
$ mkdir $HOME/go
$ export GOPATH=$HOME/go
$ export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
$ mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/user
$ mkdir $GOPATH/src/github.com/user/project
```

Then I put

```
$ go get github.com/user/project
```

Still errors with go install

```
can't load package: package github.com/golingorg/goling: no Go source files in /Users/user_name/go/src/github.com/user/project
```

I do not understand why we need files to import an external package in Go. External package means that I get something and create files from the external package.

My question is how I import an external package from scratch. Most of documents just say something like

```
 go get github.com/yasushi-saito/fifo_queue
```

this gives me "$GOPATH not set."
I am getting frustrated setting up the environment for "go get" to work, as a beginner. Thanks a lot in advance.

Summary

```
   How do I import an external package from scratch?
```

Comment: You need to set GOPATH environment variable.

Comment: Don't think anyone has mentioned this, but you don't pre-create directories or fully qualify stuff in the gopath.   The initial go get complained because you made the directory already, so it thought that it was already pulled to your filesystem and then tried to update.   deleting that 'project' directory, then re-run go get, it will work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go is a static type language thus it needs to resolve any reference to external package at compile time. The "go" tool expects the source of external packages in locally accessible path thus you need to use "go get" to download them.

From what you described, you probably did not set the GOPATH. Use ECHO $GOPATH to check if it is set correctly.

For my GO project, I normally use GOPATH as workspace, similar to virtualenv in Python or rbenv/rvm in Ruby. Let say my project "myproject" has root at /projects/myproject, my source file will be located at /projects/myproject/src/myproject and there is an import of "github.com/user/project", then

```
> cd /projects/myproject
> export GOPATH=`pwd`          # or export GOPATH=/projects/myproject
> go get github.com/user/project
```

After "go get" command, the source of "github.com/user/project" will be downloaded to /projects/myproject/src/github.com/user/project.

When you use "go build" or "go install" then, it will compile as the external packages is in the $GOPATH/src folder.

If you install Go in the default folder, you need to include Go installed bin folder in the PATH environment variable. After that GOPATH is the other environment variable you need for "go" tool to work.

Comment: Thanks, it works with downloading but go install $GOPATH/src/github.com/user/project  this one is not working saying "can't load package: package /Users/user/go/src/github.com/user/project: import "/Users/user/go/src/github.com/user/project": cannot import absolute path

Comment: @RobertKeenan, you do not need to run `go install` after `go get`, it is done automatically. If `go get` was successful, you can start using your package right away.

Comment: ok... but still not working when I run a code including this package. MacBook-Air:~ user$ go run /Users/user/Desktop/code.go 
Desktop/code.go:32:8: cannot find package "project" in any of:
 /usr/local/go/src/pkg/project (from $GOROOT)
 /Users/gyuho/go/src/project (from $GOPATH)
MacBook-Air:~ user$

Comment: @RobertKeenan: does my answer help with the getting the package to download and install?  If you haven't solved the original problem, that could explain the later ones.

Answer (score 5):

That's how I done it:

**1. Setup your workspace first**

```
 mkdir $HOME/go
 export GOPATH=$HOME/go
 export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

**2. Create the project**

```
 mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/user
 mkdir $GOPATH/src/github.com/user/hello
 touch $GOPATH/src/github.com/user/hello/hello.go
```

**3. Install it**

```
go install github.com/user/hello
```

**4. Run it**

```
cd $GOPATH/bin
./hello
```

I used the following vagrant image: https://github.com/dcoxall/vagrant-golang

Answer (score 2):

From the help output for `go get`, it says:

> By default, get uses the network to check out missing packages but does not use it to look for updates to existing packages.

When you created the `$GOPATH/src/github.com/user/project` directory prior to running `go get`, it assumed that the package had already been downloaded so skipped to the step of trying to build and install the package.  That failed because the directory contained no Go source files.

So the simple fix is to not create the folder associated with the package you are trying to download: `go get` will do that for you.