# Go not running hello world example

Tags: go, ubuntu-14.04

I am installing go in Ubuntu 14.04 and believe I have my GOPATH$ set right and can't seem to run this go install hello.go file. I got rid of any path errors that I encountered first, but I still am not seeing a successful run

Go is installed in /etc/go

```
$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/etc/go/packages"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/etc/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/etc/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

And here I made the file, edited via nano to copy the hello world example, but when I run it, nothing happens...

```
$ mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/hackg
$ nano $GOPATH/src/github.com/hackg/hello/hello.go
$ go install github.com/hackg/hello
$
```

QUESTION - it is supposed to display hello world there, proving Go is building files properly, but all I get is a fresh terminal prompt ready for a new command, no HELLO WORLD

I tried looking at other stackoverflow posts with no luck - ex [Go, Golang : does not make sense that I have to have files before import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073794/go-golang-does-not-make-sense-that-i-have-to-have-files-before-import)

Answer (score 4):

No, that command won't run your program; `go install` just made a binary you can run with `$GOPATH/bin/hello`. You can add to your `~/.bashrc` or equivalent the line `export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH`, and open a new shell (like by closing and reopening your terminal program), so you can call it with just `hello`. `go run`ning the file would compile and run, but it's reasonable to start with `go install` because that's what you're going to use for "real" programs as opposed to quick tests.

(Sounds like you're on the right track with a GOPATH and all, but for setting up a Go environment generally you might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20628918/cannot-download-gopath-not-set) helpful.)

Answer (score 1):

I did the following and it works fine for me. You may try it:-

Run the following command in your terminal:-

```
sudo apt-get install golang
```

This will install golang in your system

Add the following lines in your .bashrc file:-

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin
```

Now, close and open your shell. And run the following command to check the version of go installed in your system:-

```
go version
```

Suppose hello.go is your file containing hello world program, then do the following:-

```
go run hello.go
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I thought it would run the command, not just install it.

all I had to do once installed was type hello and hit enter

```
$ hello
hello, world
```

I suppose I didn't read the directions well. thanks **twotwotwo**

Comment: Sure. Accepting an answer makes it easier for folks to see you found it was correct.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://golang.org/doc/install) gives instructions to get your hello world example working.

To compile and install packages and dependencies:

```
go install github.com/user/hello
```

It will put an executable command named hello (or hello.exe) inside the bin directory of your workspace.

To build go program into binaries:

```
go build github.com/user/hello
```

To run:

```
$ $GOPATH/bin/hello
hello, world
```